# Android-gradle change property file when do assemble

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I read about

```
ant.propertyfile(
   file:"/projectPath/application.properties") {
      entry(key:"app.name", value:'foo')
   }
)
```

But i dont know how can i apply this for my assembleRelease process.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing diff builds(diff property values) for debug vs release is to :

```
sourceSets {

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

split the source directory tree by build-type and then in those respective source files that are now bound to a build type , you can reference diff property keys from 'gradle-properties' file:

```
configDbApiDebug=rc7
configDbRestDebug=Kw7
configDbApiProd=ovv
configDbRestProd=eoj
```